# I can't collect credit in Tiny Death Star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

So I build a service level like the man said I needed to do, but he still won't let me get the credit and give me another mission. Now I've build 2 service levels thinking maybe he wanted me to keep building them but I don't think that's it.

I built a workout center, and no credit. Then I built a millennium expr, and still no credit. It just says the same thing "according to my design you need 1 service level."

It doesn't say 'collect' or anything like it did the last 5 missions I've done. Also I didn't choose those 2 specific levels, I just hit service and the game choose it if that matters. I doubt it tho.

Can someone tell me if they're having the same issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did the building finish? The building of the floor for the missions have to finish first before you get credit.   Perhaps provide some screenshots?

Comment: Sorry brother, the 2 floors I finished are both up and running with all work slots filled.

Comment: and it is still asking for you to build a service level?

Comment: What are the names of the service levels you built?

Comment: After the jerk asked me to build a service level, I built a workout center, and no credit. Then I built a millennium expr, and still no credit. It just says the same thing "according to my design you need 1 service level. It doesn't say collect or anything like it did the last 5 missions I've done.  Also I didn't choose those 2 specific levels, I just hit service and the game choose it if that matters. I doubt it tho.

Comment: That, unfortunately, sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

So I just couldn't resist and built a 3RD service floor and it finally let me collect my credit. The mission said only 1 level but it took 3. Thanks for the help guys